# Is it good practice to use a set of .sks scenes for iPhones and another set for iPads?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to convert my iPhone app to a universal app for iPhone & iPad.

Is it a good practice to check if the device is an iPhone and then use the iPhone .sks scenes and if it's an iPad use the scenes for that? This seems like the simplest solution to me, but if it's a bad idea for any reason I'd love an explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: This is an opinion question and cannot be answered.  It depends entirely on the app and how you want to design it for the 2 devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend it.

It will lead to unnecessary duplication of effort: you need to design the same scene for both types of devices. It's also going to be a hassle to maintain both versions of the same thing: if you change a scene for iPad then you need to remember to change the scene for iPhone, and then test both.

An easier solution would be to have one .sks for both iPhone and iPad, but adjust how that scene is presented, e.g. on an iPad you could show more background that is not really going to have any effect on the gameplay (e.g. in a hill climb racing type of game you could show more sky and more ground).

Comment: I do not agree with this answer, but I will not down vote it.  It always depends on the app.  Universal app does not fit 100% app development, and you may want to offer a different experience between the iPad and the iPhone that a single SKS could not provide.  Without knowing the details of the specific app, an answer is just impossible to provide.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is the least lazy programmer I know. The rest of us regular non awesome folk want to use just 1 sks :P

Comment: @Fluidity it is not about not being lazy it is about quality.  If you want to offer your customer the same experience on both an iPad and iPhone, then yes, go universal with 1 SKS.  But there are times where you do not want to offer   the same experience.  iPhone users natively use Portrait mode, iPad users natively use Landscape.  Using this info you may want to completely redo how your HUD looks, and the answer should not be "do it in code" because it is good practice to keep design separated from functionality